# Confused about Classical TDD and Mockist

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, tdd, bdd

Here is an article: https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#ClassicalAndMockistTesting

It's in relation to Classical TDD and Mockist. My understanding was that classes should be tested in isolation therefore ALL dependencies should be stubbed / mocked. However it seems there's a large group of people the Classical TDDers who use real objects according to the article. There are various articles on the internet that emphasize that unit tests should not use real classes other than the SUT of course. For example take a look at this from Microsoft's website on stubs:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-stubs-to-isolate-parts-of-your-application-from-each-other-for-unit-testing

```
public int GetContosoPrice()
{
    var stockFeed = new StockFeed(); // NOT RECOMMENDED
    return stockFeed.GetSharePrice("COOO");
}
```

Can someone clear up my confusion?

Comment: Bear in mind that that article was written in 2007, when BDD was still primarily focused on class-level behaviour (the system-level scenarios that most people are familiar with nowadays didn't really take off until Dave Chelimsky's post later that year: http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/blog/2007/10/21/story-runner-in-plain-english/ ) . Nowadays we do the thing that Martin refers to as "classical" at a system level (using real systems, or real-ish systems, in our scenarios) but we still use mocks and stubs for class level. I do this in my codebases: https://github.com/lunivore/montecarluni

Comment: A lot of questions on BDD like this are being closed, so if you do get stuck, come on over to the BDD Google Group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/behaviordrivendevelopment

Comment: @ImranAzad what confusion? Unit testing has always been a controversial subject, so it's no big surprise that different people on the internet have different, strong opinions.

Answer (score 2):

> Can someone clear up the my confusion?

You don't seem to be confused at all - there are two *different* schools of thought on what a "unit test" is, and therefore how it should be used.

For instance, Kent Beck, in Test Driven Development By Example, writes

> The problem with driving development with small-scale tests ( *I call them "unit tests" but they don't match the accepted definition of unit tests very well*)....

Emphasis added.

It may help to keep in mind that 20 years ago, the most common testing pattern was the "throw it over the wall to QA" test.  Even in cases where automated tests were present, the disciplines required to make those tests effective were not common knowledge.

So it was important to communicate the idea that tests should be isolated from other *tests*.  If developers were going to be running tests as often as the extreme programmers were insisting that they should, then those tests needed to be reliable and fast *in wall clock time*.  Tests that don't share any mutable state (either themselves, or indirectly via the system under test) can be run effectively in parallel, reducing the wall clock time, and therefore reducing the developer interruption that they introduce.

There is a separate discipline that says, *in addition to the isolation described above*, we should also be striving for tests that check the system in isolation from other parts of the system.

If you want to get a real sense for the history of people with these different ideas talking past each other -- including the history of recognizing that they are talking past each other and trying to invent new labels, a good starting point is the C2 wiki

- http://wiki.c2.com/?UnitTest
- http://wiki.c2.com/?ShouldUnitTestsTestInteroperations
- http://wiki.c2.com/?DeveloperTest
- http://wiki.c2.com/?ProgrammerTest

For a modern perspective, you might start with Ham Vocke's [Practical Test Pyramid](https://martinfowler.com/articles/practical-test-pyramid.html#UnitTests)

Comment: Fascinating, thank you. The more I read up on this the more I realise it's not black and white.